# Create a generic flow in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I am a beginner to Power Automate and currently I am working on creation of flows.

Presently I worked on a flow to generate a PDF for a particular SharePoint list item on the click of a button in PowerApps. I have 2 lists in my site and I created 2 separate flows one for each SharePoint list. Presently I have only 2 lists but I may have 20 lists at a later point of time. Since this flow should be implemented for every list, my understanding as of now is to create 20 different flows for each list.

Is there a way to create **one** **generic flow** that will be applicable for all 20 lists in this scenario? If so kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this possible. (Please note that I enabled the Experimental Features for Power Automate - this changes the way you enter expressions and dynamic content)

- Add an "Get Lists" action to your flow. The name is pretty self-explanatory.
- I assume you used a "Get Item" action in your flow to select the item you want to convert to PDF.
- Add "Get Item" to your flow, but now select "Add custom item" for your List Name.
  [image]
- Enter one of the outputs from "Get Lists" as Dynamic Value.
- This will wrap the Get Item action in a "Apply to each" loop.
- Enter DisplayName from "Get Lists" as Dynamic Value via "Add a custom item" for List Name" again

[image]

- This should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for giving an elaborate answer. What about the HTML template? Since its different for each and every list

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing how your flow is constructed. Could you post screen shots?